# How can I disable "Destination Folder Access Denied" dialog from appearing on Win 8?

Tags: windows-8

When I was going to create a new folder on `C:\Users\username\downloads`, system showed a  "*Destination Folder Access Denied*" dialog.

[image: image of the dialog]

How can I create folders without having this dialog?

Comment: You could turn off UAC, but I'm not sure if that's desirable...

Comment: I don't think you can avoid it, other than by using your own user's folders.

Comment: @Luke - Even if he disabled UAC he wouldn't have permission to create a folder in that directory. Based on the screenshot he is likely looking at a `Users/.../Downloads` directory owned by a differeent user other then the profile he is logged into.  I don't even think, even the `Continued` button would allow him access to that folder, the user in question doesn't have ownership of the folder in question

Comment: its done.i edit permission in [username] folder...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On that folder:

1. right click the directory
2. properties
3. security tab
4. Panel: Group or username
5. your username for exp: baravak
6. click to edit
7. allow all permisions

Comment: Still have the problem : /